# Powershell Win32_ServerConnection on TS Server 2012 no result

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to execute a simple command on one of a TS part of a RDS farm and I get no result. I just want to see every connection on the TS using:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName MYTSSERVER
```

and I get no result at all. Any idea what could be the cause?

Thank you

Comment: [This question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/342533/wmi-object-to-get-current-sessions-with-client-name) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32_ServerConnection shows active connections to network shares on the machine. If you do not have active network shares or connections to them there will be no results.

I assume since they're terminal servers in an RDS farm that you're looking for remote sessions in which case you want Win32_LoggedOnUser. That said, Win32_LoggedOnUser doesn't clear sessions that have been disconnected or even closed. It shows all sessions since the last computer reboot whether that information is still valid or not.

It's incredibly annoying but the best way to list real and active sessions is to list all copies of explorer.exe running on the machine and who they belong to or use the cmd application query.exe. There are ways in PowerShell to turn the output of query.exe into objects:

```
$Users = query user /server:TERMSERV01 2>&1
$Users = $Users | ForEach-Object { (($_.trim() -replace ">" -replace "(?m)^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})\s+(\d{1,2}\s+\w+)", '$1  none  $2' -replace "\s{2,}", "," -replace "none", $null)) } | ConvertFrom-Csv
$Users
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That brings some other questions. My goal here is to get the user and resolve their ComputerName. (Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName MYTSSERVER | where username -match "test1").ComputerName doesn't really works. Do you have an idea how I could do that?

Comment: I've checked the properties for LoggenOnUser and I don't think it can accomplish what I want. I already have the username connected on the TS (with Win32_Process and GetOwner) and I need to extract the ComputerName from this session. Any idea?

Comment: @MasterGat Then why did you delete your previous question, which explained much more precisely what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I thought it would be easier in one thread, it's undeleted now.